# ASP NET Identity - conditionally check for RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity

My middleware method currently has a configurable option for "`IdentityOptions.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber`", which results in `CheckPasswordSignInAsync` method returning `IsNotAllowed = true` when phone number is not confirmed. This is expected.

I wish to make this check (`RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber`) conditional, so it only kicks in when phone number is provided.

To achieve this, I have overridden the `CheckPasswordSignInAsync` method:

```
public override async Task<SignInResult> CheckPasswordSignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password, bool lockoutOnFailure)
{
      bool confirmedNumberRequiredAlways = true; // comes from config
      bool confirmedNumberRequiredIfProvided = true; // comes from config

      base.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = confirmedNumberRequiredAlways
                                                                || confirmedNumberRequiredIfProvided && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.PhoneNumber);

      return await base.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, password, lockoutOnFailure);
}
```

So far this has worked as expected, but my questions are

1. Are there any alternate / better ways to handle this scenario?,
2. Are there any security concerns with how I have implemented this?

Comment: Phone confirmation can require an external service like twilio to confirm by sending a text message：https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp-dotnet

Comment: @Chaodeng my concern isn’t about “how to send a text message”, thank for sharing the link, but it doesn’t really address my question

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any security concerns with how I have implemented this?

The current approach will be constantly changing a global application option that should only be set at startup.

> Are there any alternate / better ways to handle this scenario?,

The override should only be checking the desired condition. which in this case is

> it only kicks in when phone number is provided.

For example

```
public override async Task<SignInResult> CheckPasswordSignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password, bool lockoutOnFailure) {
    bool confirmedNumberRequiredIfProvided = ... //from config;
    
    //pre sign in checking condition here
    if(!base.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber
        && confirmedNumberRequiredIfProvided 
        && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.PhoneNumber) 
        && !(await UserManager.IsPhoneNumberConfirmedAsync(user))) {
        //consider logging
        return SignInResult.NotAllowed;
    }
    
    return await base.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, password, lockoutOnFailure);
}
```

assuming `base.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber` is configured at startup based on `confirmedNumberRequiredAlways` retrieved from configuration

Comment: `confirmedNumberRequiredAlways` and `confirmedNumberRequiredIfProvided` are one-way mutually exclusinve, in that, they can both be `false` the same time. If `confirmedNumberRequiredAlways` is `true`, It should be safe to ignore the `confirmedNumberRequiredIfProvided` parameter and just do the validation?